# Am I creating a memory leak in C?

Tags: c, struct, memory-leaks, malloc

I am recieving a warning on

```
*data = realloc(*data, number * sizeof * data);
```

The Warning:

> "realloc" might return NULL pointer: assigning NULL pointer to "*data", which is passed as an argument to "realloc", which will cause the original memory block to be leaked.

Am I really leaking memory? If so, how would I fix this? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct thing {
    char* hullo;
}thing;

void increase(datas, number)
{
    char** data = datas;
    *data = realloc(*data, number * sizeof * data);
}

main()
{
    thing* thingy = malloc(1 * sizeof * thingy);
    thingy[0].hullo = "Hullo";
    int number = 1;
    increase(&thingy, number);
    printf("%s", thingy[0].hullo);
    free(thingy);
}
```

Comment: The message seems pretty clear. `realloc` can return NULL. In that case it doesn't free the original pointer but since it has been overwritten you can't free it either. So hence it's a lost pointer and a potential leak. Fix by assigning `realloc` result to tmp pointer and checking that before  overwriting the original `*data` pointer.

Comment: How is this code compiling? You're missing type declarations in the parameter list of `increase()`.

Comment: @Barmar These are K&R prototypeless functions. They are deprecared but still supported in C. In C99 and later you have to specify the type, though, `int` is not the default.